# VS2012 - How to check during runtime if program runs with debugging or not?

Tags: debugging, runtime

VS2012, C++ project.

When I execute the program I can use "Start Debugging" or "Start Without Debugging".

Is it possible to retrieve that information during run time ?

My goal is to create a log.txt file and I want to write that information to it.

Answer (score 0):

VisualStudio generates `_DEBUG` and `NDEBUG` as a define. You can check it at compile time. And it would be wrong to say that you are checking this fact at run time. After you have compiled a code once, you will have an executable file with or without debugging symbols. That means that you check a type of build only in a compile time.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::cout << "DEBUG\n";
#else
    std::cout << "RELEASE\n";
#endif
```

**Edit**
In your case you can just call `IsDebuggerPresent()` function (don't forget to include Windows.h) to determine the type of run.

Comment: This wasn't my question.. In each of those modes you can run with debugging or not..

Comment: @brkeyal, Sorry about that, my bad. I have updated the answer, hope it can help.